# jQuery Mobile, remove space in collapsible with listview

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-mobile-collapsible

When I click on the top left button and click hardware, the space between each li is to much. I would like it to be 0. How can I do that?

I have tried varoius solutions, but nothing works.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mfu4jvb/)

I have tried some custom css:

```
 .custom-li {
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-width:0 !important;
}

.custom-li +li {
    border-top-width: 0 !important;  
}

.custom-li li[data-role="collapsible"]{
    margin: 0 !important;   
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
    border-width:0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in your css

```
.ui-listview, .ui-listview > li{margin-bottom:-22px;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4mfu4jvb/3/)**

Comment: Thank you so much - I've spent the last hour looking for that :P

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-listview {line-height: 0;}
```